# How do I find the original area of a square given that two 1 inch parallel cuts would divide it into three even piece? (Diagram included)

Tags: area

If I take a perfect square, and make two parallel 1 inch cuts (as seen in diagram) this will divide the square into three perfectly equal sections. What is the original area of the square?

This is a question for my math seminar class, and I've really struggled with it. I've tried to make some triangles out of the square using the lines from the parallel cuts in it, and found that they were similar. Trying to relate the triangles and solve for the area of one third (given the value of 1 from the parallel cut), got me nowhere. All help is appreciated!

[image: Square Diagram]

Comment: You have to decide whether you care about the peanut butter and jelly or whether this is about the area of a third of a square

Comment: Is the fact that the names of the children are Abby and Nolan is an essential data for solving the problem :) ?

Comment: Sorry, I just copied and pasted the entire thing from my problem set. I've cut it down so it hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: Stop making endless, and now trivial edits to your question.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the diagram for me Parcly Taxel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As shown in the above diagram, the side legnth is $s = a + b$

The area of one of the triangles is $ \frac{1}{2} a s = \frac{1}{3} s^2 $

Hence, $a = \dfrac{2}{3} s $ and $b = \frac{1}{3} s $

Now, we have $\tan \theta = \dfrac{a}{s} = \dfrac{2}{3} $

From which $\sec \theta = \sqrt{ \tan^2 \theta + 1 } = \dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{3} $

Finally, note that $b = \frac{1}{3} s =  \sec \theta = \dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{3} $

Hence, $s = \sqrt{13} $ and the area is $s^2 = 13 $

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It was very clear and helpful.